# AutoLayout issue UITable View header section: Adding image in the left does not works fine

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have added a custom image to my UITableView header section. It's working fine when the screen is in portrait mode. Large gap appears in landscape mode. Can any one help me out?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    var headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
    var myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width - 70, 40)
    print(myLabel.frame)
    myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    myLabel.text = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 230,y: 0,width: 100,height: 40))
    button.tag = section
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    headerView.addSubview(button)
    headerView.addSubview(myLabel)
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // the button is image - set image
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icoDraft"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    let tapOnCardCell: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HHLabTestExaminationViewController.handleTapOnSectionImage(_:)))
    button.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnCardCell)

    return headerView
}
```

Now the title for header sections are

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return "Exam"
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return "News"
    }
    else if(section == 2)
    {
        return "Movie"
    }
    else if(section == 3)
    {
        return "Sport"
    }
    return ""
}
```

This image is my output when the screen is in portrait orientation:
[image]

This is when the screen is in landscape orientation. How can i fix this gap in landscape?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any autolayout code when you set up this header view. However, this simple layout can be handled without autolayout.

```
headerView.autoResizesSubviews = true
myLabel.autoResizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
button.autoResizingMask = .flexibleLeftMargin
```

Answer (score 1):

As @DaveWeston says, there is no auto layout code, and his answer should work fine. If you want auto layout, here is what it would look like for the button.

(Note this is Swift 3 vs. 2.x in the OP's code).

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.tag = section
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerView.addSubview(button)

    // Autolayout for button
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: button,
                                                 attribute: .height,
                                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                                 toItem: headerView,
                                                 attribute: .height,
                                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                                 constant: 0.0))
    button.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: button,
                                                 attribute: .width,
                                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                                 toItem: nil,
                                                 attribute: .width,
                                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                                 constant: 40.0))
    button.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: button,
                                                 attribute: .trailing,
                                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                                 toItem: headerView,
                                                 attribute: .trailing,
                                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                                 constant: 0.0))
    button.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: button,
                                                 attribute: .centerY,
                                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                                 toItem: headerView,
                                                 attribute: .centerY,
                                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                                 constant: 0.0))
```

Comment: its really awesome solution  Thanks :) :) . This worked too for me